# Entity Framework : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

Tags: entity-framework, types, null

When I execute `update-database` command, it shows this error message

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: type
>
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project project, Int32 shellVersion)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebSiteProject(Project project)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetTargetDir(Project project)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>
> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: type"?

Comment: this a bug in vs2022 . try with vs 2019

Answer (score 159):

For those who do have this problem using Visual Studio 2022, there are at least two fixes:

- Switch back to Visual Studio 2019, as it doesn't work yet in the 2022 version if you are using an older Entity Framework version.
- Update Entity Framework to 6.4.4 to resolve it

On the [relevant issue file on the Entity Framework 6 GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1916), project member ajcvickers [commented on 2021-11-18](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/1916#issuecomment-972609832):

> [...] EF 6.2 doesn't work. You will need to update to EF 6.4.4. We have so far been unable to reproduce this with EF 6.4.4.

While numerous users have reported upgrading to EF 6.4.4 resolves their problem, the issue is still open, as there are users who can't downgrade to Visual Studio 2019 *or* upgrade Entity Framework, as those changes could break pipelines.

Comment: I upgraded ef 6.2 to 6.4, my problem solved. thanks!

Comment: Arthur Vickers is not a "project member"... he's the Principal Software Engineering Manager for the Entity Framework team at Microsoft. 

Comment: ` the issue is still open, as there are users who can't downgrade to Visual Studio 2019 or upgrade Entity Framework, as those changes could break pipelines` If anyone is in that situation. I confirmed, that it is possible to create the migrations in a separate branch with EF 6.4.4. and merge it into the main branch still on version 6.1.3.

Comment: For me the trick was to upgrade ALL PROJECTS in my solution to 6.4.4 then restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 34):

I got this error in VS 2022, while I was using EF version 6.1.3. I upgraded EF to version 6.4.4 and the issue got resolved. The .Net version was 4.8.

Comment: This repeats the answer from Apfelkuacha a month ago.

Answer (score 12):

**Solution:** For me solution was as easy as restarting visual studio.

**Senario:** I have solution like this:

[image: solution explorer]

I changed startup project from `Host` to the `UI.Web` project which contains web.config  and then running the `update-database` command but it gave me the `Value cannot be null.` exception until I restart visual studio and rerun the  `update-database` command. This time it behaved normally.

Comment: You can avoid having to set this each time by calling the update-database command with the --StartupProjectName param.  

  
'update-database -ProjectName B2B.Data -StartupProjectName B2B.UI.Web'

Answer (score 7):

Had exactly this error message (`Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'type')`) when I added a migration. Tried the other solutions (restart VS) but they didn't work.

After a long time searching I found the source of the problem.
I made a mistake when setting the 'InverseProperty' annotation in one of my POCOs:

```
public class Workflow{
 [InverseProperty("Workflow")]
 public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; } 
 ...
}
public class Node{
 public int WorkflowId{ get; set; } 
 public Workflow Workflow{ get; set; } 
 ...
}
```

instead of

```
public class Workflow{
 [InverseProperty("WorkflowId")] //needs to be Workflow instead of WorkflowId
 public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; } 
 ...
}
```

I wished the EF Exception would have been a bit more precise.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution in VS 2022 without having to install VS 2019 is to use Migrate.exe, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe) it explains how to use it. It is more or less like this:

```
Migrate.exe your_app_ef_model.dll /startupConfigurationFile="your_app.config" /targetMigration="migrationName"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're facing this type of error in Visual Studio 2022 **Entity Framework: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type**

follow these steps:-

Step 1:- Update your EF to Version 6.4.4

Step 2:- Restart your application

Step 3:- Run your migration command

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in MVC 5 in VS 2022 but when I run it on VS 2019. That fixed my error.

Comment: thank you, it worked for me when i switched from vs2022 to 2019 just to add migration

Answer (score 1):

This issue is most commonly raised when the ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot file in the Migrations folder no longer matches the entity relationship.

Perhaps deleting this file and running the migration could solve the problem. Anyways, this file is again created while add-migration command is executed.

Comment: Note that this answer applies to EntityFramework Core specifically. EntityFramework doesn't have such snapshot files.

Answer (score 1):

Update entityframework to version 6.4.4 and then
Use EntityFramework6\Add-Migration command, microsoft have changed name of cmdmidlet

Its work from me

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that my ip address has changed and the target database - behind a firewall - was no longer accepting connections from my machine.

For this flavour of the problem the solution is changing the firewall settings or fixing any other connection issues.