# EF Update-Database Error: Value cannot be null Parameter name: type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

I try to execute command `update-database` in PMC and always get this error msg. I know theres [another article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41777590/16898096) basically has the same error but i tried every answer and nothing works.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetProjectTypes(Project project, Int32 shellVersion)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.IsWebSiteProject(Project project)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.ProjectExtensions.GetTargetDir(Project project)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.GetFacade(String configurationTypeName, Boolean useContextWorkingDirectory)
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
```

BTW I'm using VS2022 preview.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try updating EntityFramework package to the latest version.
I was having the same problem with EF 6.1.3, but then updated to 6.4.4 and it worked fine on VS2022 preview.

Comment: It works fine now!!! amazing!!! I stuck for this for weeks, so appreciated!

Comment: thanks!, in my case the problem was relative to an inexistant parameter-less constructor, when I updated to 6.4 the error did appears into the console.

Comment: I encountered the same issue if I open a 4.6.1 in vs2022 but it works just fine in vs2019

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make it work is to use VS2019.

When you install Entity `Framework 6.3 <` you will see the message below:

```
A version of Entity Framework older than 6.3 is also installed. The newer tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Update-Database' for the older version.
```

Tooling has been updated and unfortunately Visual Studio 2022 is not compatible with older Entity Framework versions when running commands via Package Manager Console

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the `connection` parameter. My problem was I was trying to execute SQL with a transaction that was being rolled back to test that the migration would work. Once I removed the `BEGIN/ROLLBACK TRAN` statement it worked.